# Simulink S-Function with C++ code compiles but gives an error at generation/set-up

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink

I have a C++ routine that I would like to pack in a Simulink S-Function. This C++ routines calls other routines that are in several other C++ files.

I could manage to have everything compiled (i.e. the mexglx file is generated) using the legacy_code tool. However, the following warning is issued:

```
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.4.4-14ubuntu5)".  The earliest gcc version
supported  with mex is "4.1".  The latest version tested for use with mex 
is "4.2". To download a different version of gcc, visit http://gcc.gnu.org
```

The problem arises when I try to generate the S-Function block by issuing the command:

```
legacy_code('slblock_generate', def);
```

At this point, the following error mentioning the GLIBCXX version is raised:

```
??? Error using ==> iAddSfunctionBlock at 183
Error due to multiple causes.

Error in ==>
/opt/matlab/toolbox/simulink/simulink/+legacycode/@LCT/generateslblock.p>
generateslblock at 55


Error in ==> /opt/matlab/toolbox/simulink/simulink/legacy_code.p>legacy_code at
160


Caused by:
    Error using ==> iAddSfunctionBlock at 183
    Invalid MEX-file 'sfun_vectorRotation_b.mexglx':
    /opt/matlab/bin/glnx86/../../sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version
    `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by sfun_vectorRotation_b.mexglx).
    Error using ==> iAddSfunctionBlock at 183
    Error while obtaining sizes from MEX S-function 'sfun_vectorRotation_b' in
    'untitled1/sfun_vectorRotation_b'. MATLAB error message:
    Invalid MEX-file 'sfun_vectorRotation_b.mexglx':
    /opt/matlab/bin/glnx86/../../sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version
    `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by sfun_vectorRotation_b.mexglx).
```

Honestly I am a bit lost at this point. I do not know if downgrading the g++ compilator would be enough or if I have to do some other things. Do you have a possible solution for this issue?

I am using Matlab 2009b in an Ubuntu 10.10 OS, and the g++ version is:

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Miquel

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could solve the problem myself. Just download and install (via `./configure`, `make` and `make install`) a supported version of gcc (anyone between 4.1 and 4.2 will do). In my case I tried gcc-4.2 and it works fine.

Thanks anyway!

Miquel